# How to change primaryRoadColor in Osmand Android?

Tags: android, osmand

I tried changing the `primaryRoadColor` value to `ff0000`. When I compile, it is replaced with the default `ff80a0` value. How and where can I create custom color for roads?

In my render folder, I have the following XML:

`default.render.xml, Depends-template.render.xml, hud.render.xml, LightRS.render.xml, nautical.render.xml, regions.render.xml, skimap.render.xml, standalone-template.render.xml, test.render.xml, Topo-map-assimilation.render.xml,Touring-view_(more-contrast-and-details).render.xml, UniRS.render.xml`

I followed this [link](http://osmand.net/help/docs/Custom_Rendering_How-To.htm), it didn't work out.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that [this tutorial](http://osmand.net/help/docs/Custom_Rendering_How-To.htm) needs updating, a complete "Hello World!" style example would've been nice.

This is how I did it in **OsmAnd+ 2.3.5**.

My data storage folder (`Settings -> General Settings -> Data storage folder`) was in:

```
/storage/sdcard1/osmand-plus/osmand
```

so the custom renderer file had to go to:

```
/storage/sdcard1/osmand-plus/osmand/rendering
```

This directory may be empty at first but as you select map styles from `Configure map -> Map style` OsmAnd will drop the corresponding renderer XML files into that directory.

**NOTE:** You have to completely shut down the app and restart it again after adding new renderers or making changes to the existing ones for the app to pick the changes up.

I went the "inheritance" route and created a file called `BLACK_ROADS.render.xml` (following the `<name-of-renderer>.render.xml` naming requirement) that extended the `default` (`default.render.xml`) renderer.

Here is the content of my renderer. I made it into a sort of a template so I can later see what else can go into this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- depends="default" -> default.render.xml -->
<renderingStyle name="Paints the roads black in day mode, white in night mode" 
    depends="default" defaultColor="#ffffff" version="1">

    <renderingAttribute name="primaryRoadColor">
        <!-- 40 -> 25% opacity, 80 -> 50% opacity, C0 -> 75% opacity, FF -> 100% opacity -->
        <!-- or remove first two hex digits for 100% opacity -->
        <!-- NIGHT MODE -->
        <case nightMode="true" attrColorValue="#80ffffff"/> <!-- white -->
        <!-- DAY MODE -->
        <case attrColorValue="#80000000"/> <!-- black -->
    </renderingAttribute>

    <!-- These are "global" variables (can have many of each), which 
         can be referenced throughout the file. -->
    <!--
    <renderingAttribute/>
    <renderingConstant/>
    <renderingProperty/>
    -->

    <!-- This section determines the order in which objects are rendered.
         Higher values will be on top. -->
    <order/>

    <!-- This section determines how text object are displayed. -->
    <text/>

    <!-- This section determines how point objects, which typically 
         have an icon associated with them, are displayed. -->
    <point/>

    <!-- This section determines how polygon objects are displayed. -->
    <polygon/>

    <!-- This section determines the look of roads, footpaths, coastlines etc.  
         Basically everything that is a line goes into this section. -->
    <line/>

</renderingStyle>
```

And here are the results:

- OsmAnd style
- new BLACK ROADS menu entry (taken from the file name)
- BLACK ROADS style day mode
- BLACK ROADS style night mode

[image: OsmAnd style]
[image: new BLACK ROADS menu entry]
[image: BLACK ROADS style day mode]
[image: BLACK ROADS style night mode]

Comment: Nice job! Do you know how to modify style of tolled roads? They can be differentiated from the regular ones only in big zooms, I want to make them visible always, i.e. to increase thickness.

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful example - it works. Unfortunately, only at high zoom levels. Do you know how to make it work for all zoom levels at which primary roads are shown?

Comment: @BernhardHiller You need to additionally specify `primaryRoadLowZoomColor` (works the same way, with a `renderingAttribute` bloc). That makes it work as expected. I agree that it's not very well documented...

Comment: Another issue I ran into is that some data is not compiled into the offline files at lower zoom levels - for example, I wanted to change cycleways to be visible already at lower zoom levels (e.g. 11), however that is not possible due to the way the offline files are compiled. In order to do this, I'd need to change [rendering_types.xml](https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-resources/blob/master/obf_creation/rendering_types.xml) also, to specify a lower minzoom there, and then recompile the offline .obf files from OpenStreetMap data myself, which takes a lot of time and RAM. So there are limits.

Comment: @JonasCz-ReinstateMonica I discussed a small project recently in the OpenStreetMap forum at https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=67937

Comment: @BernhardHiller "_I'll work on a cycle map_". I'll be following that thread with interest. While I did succeed in my goal of making dedicated cycleways more visible just by modifying the local `rendering.xml` files of osmand (just coloring and size), that fact that you cannot have them visible at less than a certain minzoom without recompiling the .obf file is annoying. Importing GPX exports from overpass-turbo also works, but is annoying and doesn't look nice.

Comment: If your project does get off the ground, I might even rent an hourly server to render the areas i'm interested in - and obviously upload them somewhere after for anyone interested.

Answer (score 1):

I edited this included (mapnik) XML and added couple of things from default file to make a new style. The ones that come with osmAnd app are really overwhelming to look at, especially while on the road. Colors are too intense and too many, so in this file I made it similar to Google Maps which is much easier on your eyes. Non important roads are white, and the main roads are yellow.

This should answer your question as I've annotated the parts I've changed, so if you look for "eml" you can find them. Specifically, if you want to change the road colors, look for Road-0 through Road-4. These are five big roads. Smaller ones are also in that section.

When making changes, keep in mind there are several conditions under which your changes may not be reflected. This is because additional options have a set of their own styles. There is **Road Styles**, just pick one and edit only that, not to be confused. I picked *German road atlas*. Also there's **Map Mode** (Day/Night/etc), I picked *Day*. This all is very versatile but for me a single map style would be good enough.

`You can download my xml file here (eml.render.xml) :` https://pastebin.com/7MystwDv

1) copy it to "rendering" folder of your osmAnd

File location, depends on the version, can be:
/storage/sdcard1/osmand-plus/osmand/rendering
 or 
/Internal storage/Android/data/net.osmand/files/rendering

2) Start the osmAnd and go to Configure Map, and click on Map Style. In this case you will have a new style "eml" derived from eml.render.xml filename you've copied.

3) After selecting that, change Road style to: "German road atlas" because that's the only one I've changed

4) Map Mode: "Day"  also the only one I've changed

If you're planing to edit these files, having an editor that shows you the hex color helps a lot. I'm using Android Studio, it's an overkill of course, but I already had it installed. There should be others much smaller editors that offer this option.

For reference, here's a screenshot of this style: [image]

Comment: Do you know how to increase thickness of tolled roads?

Answer (score 0):

If someone's *only* interested in colour changes, then [this OSM diary entry](https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/SomeoneElse/diary/391499) that I wrote last month might help.

Beyond that I'm not aware of a "hello world" type example of some of the things that should be possible based on the [how to](https://osmand.net/help/docs/Custom_Rendering_How-To.htm) document.